# After first successful run, following TypeError pops up: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, typeerror

I have kind of a weird problem with a dictionary within a loop function. The first time I run the code everything works well but if I run it a second time it gives me the following error:
`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`.

Now I would need to run a loop and have this part of the code run several times but I just can't figure out why it works the first time and not a second/third time.
The dictionary I try to update looks the same except that some of the numbers in the dataframes changed (which is on purpose). What seems to cause the error are the last 4 lines in the code which are updating the dictionary for the next run.
Hopefully someone can help me or point me in the right direction - thanks!

[image: TypeError after second run]

```
receipts = {}
for count, bank in enumerate(banks_final_receipt):
    df = settlement_data_receive.loc[settlement_data_receive['Bank'] == bank]
    df= df.drop(['Bank'], axis=1)
    df.columns = ['curr', bank]
    #exec(f'receipt_{bank} = df')
    name = f'receipt_{bank}'
    receipts[name] = df


banks_final_receipt_Citi = banks_final_receipt.copy()
banks_final_receipt_Citi.remove('CITI')

df = payout['payout_CITI']
df['CL_Inc'] = df['CITI']

for bank in banks_final_receipt_Citi:
    df = df.merge(receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'], on='curr', how='left')
    df = df.fillna(0)

for bank in banks_final_receipt_Citi:
    
    df[f'{bank}_leftover'] = df[f'{bank}']   
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if  df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')] != 0: 
            if df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')] + df.loc[(index,bank)] < 0: 
                df.loc[(index,f'{bank}_leftover')] = 0
                df.loc[(index,bank)] = float(df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')]) * -1
            else: 
                df.loc[(index,f'{bank}_leftover')] = df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')] + df.loc[(index,bank)]
                df.loc[(index,bank)] = df.loc[(index,bank)] - df.loc[(index,f'{bank}_leftover')]
                
            if df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')] + df.loc[(index,bank)] >= 0: df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')] = 0
            else: df.loc[(index,'CL_Inc')] = df.loc[(index,bank)]  
        else: 
            df.loc[(index,f'{bank}_leftover')] = df.loc[(index,bank)]
            df.loc[(index,bank)] = 0

    receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'] = pd.merge(receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'], df[['curr',f'{bank}_leftover']], on='curr', how='left')
    receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'].loc[receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'][f'{bank}_leftover'].isnull(),f'{bank}_leftover'] = receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'][f'{bank}']
    receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'] = receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'].drop([f'{bank}'], axis=1)
    receipts[f'receipt_{bank}'].columns = [['curr', f'{bank}']]
```

bank_final_receipt_Citi:
`['BAML','JPM','SMBC','SVB']`

df:

[image: df]

Getting the same error when I just try to merge the dataframes afterwards, something seems like to cause the "receipts" dataframe to be corrupted and not able to merge anymore:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTtgU.jpg)

Comment: Some context would help. What does `banks_final_receipt_Citi` and `df` look like? Can you paste `df.head()` and `banks_final_receipt_Citi` into the question as formatted text?

Comment: Hi Derek, the df incl. information that will be reset every time the final loop runs and banks_final_receipt_Citi is a list that incl. all banks except the bank in question (i.e., Citi). I added the screenshots to the question. Thanks for your help!